# Questionable output from LeaveOneOut

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

My dataset has 93 observations and 24 features. I am using a SVM model to classify into either class 0 or class 1.

I have some questions about the Leave One Out Cross Validation approach I used, specifically regarding the accuracy, precision, recall, and AUC

I have tested the methods in my code below, but something is definitely wrong, which you can see from the accuracy standard deviation of 0.91.

What did I miss?

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

```py
#creates feature set and class#

x = np.array(df.drop(['target'], 1))
y = np.array(df['target'])
xs = scale(x)



#Here is the LOOCV code to achieve accuracy#

svm_model = SVC(C=0.1,kernel ='linear', probability = True)   
loo = LeaveOneOut(93)

acc = cross_val_score(estimator=svm_model,
                                      X=xs,
                                      y=y,
                                      cv=loo)
print(acc)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (acc.mean(), acc.std() * 2))
#prints 0.71 +- 0.91 
    [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]



#Here is what I tried to get precision and recall#

predicted = cross_val_predict(svm_model, xs, y, cv = loo)
print (recall_score(y, predicted))
#prints 23%

print (precision_score(y, predicted))
#prints 46%


print (roc_auc_score(y, predicted))
#prints 56%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SkLearn documentation for [LeaveOneOut](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html), it appears that the `split()` method is actually responsible for generating train/test indices for all the CV splits:

```
loo = LeaveOneOut()
loo.split(xs, y)
```

I believe that the above two lines should replace the line, `loo = LeaveOneOut(93)`, that you had written. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L69) for the `__init__()` method used by LeaveOneOut, you can see that nothing is done with any arguments that may be passed to it. I believe that this is why you saw no error message when you created your `loo` object by passing to it the integer 93.

Indeed, if you scroll to just right underneath the source code for the `__init__()` method, you'll see that the `split` method actually accepts arguments (the training data, and labels) and then yields the train/test indices for each CV fold (93 folds, in your case).

Comment: That helped get me to the answer. Thank you so much!